# How to create a new file or directory using ranger?

Tags: ranger

I want to create a new file or directory with ranger. I suppose I could use `mkdir` or `touch`, but I'm not sure if these would go in the current directory as viewed in ranger.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To create a directory in [ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/), just type

```
:mkdir exampledir
```

or,

```
:touch examplefile
```

Comment: but how can you see the result of the command? what if something went wrong (read only FS, access rights, etc)?

Answer (score 29):

The accepted answer is correct, but someone might prefer to get these commands typed just by pressing one key. As @jaustin describes in his answer, one need to have keys mapped in `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf` config file.

If you copied default configuration files by

```
ranger --copy-config=all
```

then you already have the shortest access to `mkdir` / `touch`:

- <kbd>F7</kbd> - mkdir (config: `map <F7> console mkdir%space`)
- <kbd>Insert</kbd> - touch (config: `map <INSERT>   console touch%space`)

Mine current version of Ranger is **1.9.2**.

BTW: extra space at the end of `map c console touch␣` doesn't work. Only `map c console touch%space` will work.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `:touch somefile`, but I prefer it mapped to a key.

`:map c console touch`  (note the extra space at the end)

Place this at the bottom of your `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf` minus the leading `:`

Answer (score 5):

For creating a new file that you intend to immediately edit, using:

```
:edit new_file_name
```

is slightly faster. This will open the file in `vim`. Note that you'd need to save it in `vim` (e.g. with <kbd>:w<CR></kbd>) before it appears (contrary to `:touch`, which will create the file immediately).